# How to HardCode a string array?

Tags: c#, string

I basically want to type in a string[] and and be able to do a foreach based on newline.  I tried like this but I dont believe this works.

```
static string[] mystrings = {"here"+
"there"+
"mine"
}
```

and I want to foreach it and get back one at a time.  Is this possible?

Comment: FYI: Your code actually does compile, but it results in **one** string in the array: `heretheremine`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to add `new[]` or `new string[]` in front of the curly-brace list. And use commas, not plus signs. As in

```
string[] mystrings = new[] { "here", "there", "mine" };
```

FYI, the `new[]` shortcut is syntactic sugar provided by C#, which infers that you specifically mean `new string[]`. If you are creating an array of mixed types (such as an array of `object`), you will have to explicitly use `new object[]`, because otherwise the C# compiler won't know which type you are implying. That is:

```
// Doesn't work, even though assigning to variable of type object[]
object[] myArgs = new[] { '\u1234', 9, "word", new { Name = "Bob" } };

// Works
object[] myArgs = new object[] { '\u1234', 9, "word", new { Name = "Bob" } };

// Or, as Jeff pointed out, this also works -- it's still commas, though!
object[] myArgs = { '\u1234', 9, "word", new { Name = "Bob" } };

// ...althouth this does not, since there is not indication of type at all
var myArgs = { '\u1234', 9, "word", new { Name = "Bob" } };
```

Comment: You don't strictly need the `new[]` part if it's initializing the variable, but it's always a good idea to include it.

Comment: If I want to put the declaration of the array into a parameter for a function then you do need the new[] part. So something like: DoSomething(new[] {"a", "b"})  If the new[] is left off, it confuses C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
static string[] myStrings = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

foreach(string s in myStrings)
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static string[] items = new[] { "here", "there", "mine" };
```

and then

```
foreach (string item in items)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```

But keep in mind that arrays can be initialized once and then you can not add more items, I would suggets using generic list `List<string>` instead.

```
IList<string> items = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Comment: You can always use `Array.Resize`, even with explicitly initialized arrays.

Comment: Literally you are right, there is such possibility. This is pretty interesting method which was added since `.NET 3.5`, but when arrays have been used very often (before geenrics was introduced since 2.0) this method was not available so no chance to resize